# Exchanging data between Raspberry Pi and Arduino using SPI

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi, spi

I have a problem with data exchange between Raspberry Pi 3b+ (SPI Master) and Arduino Mega (SPI Slave). The problem is that I can send/receive data OK, but only for the first try after Arduino powering on. Every next try fails - means I receive unexpected data from Arduino. When I turn Arduino off and on again I can send/receive data fine, but again only for the first time (I mean by this that for the first time I run SPI Master code on Raspberry.)
Turning on/off Raspberry, resetting Arduino using reset button or uploading/flashing Arduino do not help. Problem exists until Arduino is restarted.

The issue did not exist until today morning, before that the code was under development. Today I got it working and I am sure I tested it for a couple of minutes and it worked fine. I made a backup, but later, when I restored it, the issue already existed.

I probably must have done some bug and I do not see where it is :(, or this might be a hardware issue... but I did not touch the hardware and I do not have spare Raspberry/Arduino to test it.

HOW TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE:
Compile and flash the code on Arduino (SPI Slave) - the entire code bellow:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <SPI.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);

unsigned char SPIbuf [100];
unsigned char SPIbufOUT [100];
volatile byte pos;
volatile boolean ProcessSPI;
int SendSPI;

void setup()
{
    //LCD conf
    lcd.begin(16,2);
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Initializing...");

    //Serial conf
    Serial.begin (115200);
    Serial.print("\nInitializing...");

    //LED conf
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

    //SPI Slave conf
    pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
    SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
    SPI.attachInterrupt();

    //Other declarations
    pos = 0;
    ProcessSPI = false;
    SendSPI=0;

    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Ready          ");
    Serial.print("\nReady");
}

ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
    if (pos < sizeof SPIbuf)
    {
        switch (SendSPI)
        {
            case 0:
                    SPIbuf [pos] = SPDR;

                    Serial.print("\n[debug] SPIbuf [");
                    Serial.print(pos);
                    Serial.print("] = ");
                    Serial.print(SPIbuf [pos]);

                    if (SPIbuf [0] == 111)      //Checking READ request 111
                        {
                            Serial.print("\n[0] Received READ request [111]");
                            SPDR=255;           //Sending READ request confirmation 255
                            Serial.print("\n[0] Sending confirmation [255]");
                            pos=0;
                            SendSPI=20;
                            ProcessSPI = true;
                        }
                    break;
            case 20:
                    SPDR=SPIbufOUT[pos];            //sending data

                    Serial.print("\n[");
                    Serial.print(pos);
                    Serial.print("]");
                    Serial.print(" sending: ");
                    Serial.print(SPIbufOUT[pos]);

                    pos++;
                    if(pos==20)
                        {
                            SendSPI=0;
                            SPIbuf [0]=0;
                            pos=0;

                        }
                    break;
        }
    }
}  // end of interrupt service routine (ISR) for SPI


void loop()
{
      if (ProcessSPI)
        {
              Serial.print("\nPreparing for sending data...");
              switch (SendSPI)
              {
                  case 20:                  // 'Read data' procedure signal definition
                      SPIbufOUT[0]=1;
                      SPIbufOUT[1]=2;
                      SPIbufOUT[2]=3;
                      SPIbufOUT[3]=10;
                      SPIbufOUT[4]=50;
                      SPIbufOUT[5]=255;
                      SPIbufOUT[6]=13;
                      SPIbufOUT[7]=15;
                      SPIbufOUT[8]=4;
                      SPIbufOUT[9]=51;
                      SPIbufOUT[10]=52;
                      SPIbufOUT[11]=10;
                      SPIbufOUT[12]=11;
                      SPIbufOUT[13]=111;
                      SPIbufOUT[14]=255;
                      SPIbufOUT[15]=155;
                      SPIbufOUT[16]=100;
                      SPIbufOUT[17]=253;
                      SPIbufOUT[18]=254;
                      SPIbufOUT[19]=255;
                      break;
              }
              ProcessSPI = false;
        }
}


int RobomowRead(int TargetDevice)
{
    int TDValue=0;
    switch (TargetDevice)
    {
    case 1:                             //Test DIODE
        TDValue=digitalRead(13);
        break;
    default:
        //
        break;
    }
    return TDValue;
}
```

Compile the code for Raspberry Pi (SPI Master) - the entire code bellow:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <minmea.h>
#include <wiringPiSPI.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SPI_CHANNEL 0
#define SPI_CLOCK_SPEED 1000000
#define INDENT_SPACES "  "


void CRC16(unsigned char * Data, unsigned short * CRC, unsigned char Bytes);




int main ()
{

        int fd = wiringPiSPISetupMode(SPI_CHANNEL, SPI_CLOCK_SPEED, 0);
        if (fd == -1) {
                printf("Failed to init SPI communication.\n");
                return -1;
                }

        unsigned char SPIbuf[40] = { 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };// RFID read request
        unsigned char SPIbufIN[40] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };// Recive buffer


        printf("Sending data request.\n");
        wiringPiSPIDataRW(SPI_CHANNEL, SPIbuf, 1);
        usleep(5000);

        wiringPiSPIDataRW(SPI_CHANNEL, SPIbuf, 1);
        usleep(5000);

        int ans=SPIbuf[0];
        printf("ans: %d\n", ans);

                for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
                        {
                        wiringPiSPIDataRW(SPI_CHANNEL, SPIbuf, 1);
                        usleep(5000);
                        SPIbufIN[i]=SPIbuf[0];
                        printf("   receiving [%d] = %d\n", i,  SPIbufIN[i]);
                        }

        return 0;
}
```

Run the Raspberry code.

You should get something like this - for the first run... on RPI

```
Sending data request.
ans: 255
   receiving [0] = 1
   receiving [1] = 2
   receiving [2] = 3
   receiving [3] = 10
   receiving [4] = 50
   receiving [5] = 255
   receiving [6] = 13
   receiving [7] = 15
   receiving [8] = 4
   receiving [9] = 51
   receiving [10] = 52
   receiving [11] = 10
   receiving [12] = 11
   receiving [13] = 111
   receiving [14] = 255
   receiving [15] = 155
   receiving [16] = 100
   receiving [17] = 253
   receiving [18] = 254
   receiving [19] = 255
```

And you should get something similar on Arduino's serial:

```
Initializing...
Ready
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 111
[0] Received READ request [111]
[0] Sending confirmation [255]
Preparing for sending data...
[0] sending: 1
[1] sending: 2
[2] sending: 3
[3] sending: 10
[4] sending: 50
[5] sending: 255
[6] sending: 13
[7] sending: 15
[8] sending: 4
[9] sending: 51
[10] sending: 52
[11] sending: 10
[12] sending: 11
[13] sending: 111
[14] sending: 255
[15] sending: 155
[16] sending: 100
[17] sending: 253
[18] sending: 254
[19] sending: 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 254
```

When you run the code for the next time on Raspberry Pi, you will get 'some' data - however not the one sent from Arduino, but it does not look to be random. Please see bellow:

```
Sending data request.
ans: 47
   receiving [0] = 255
   receiving [1] = 47
   receiving [2] = 255
   receiving [3] = 47
   receiving [4] = 255
   receiving [5] = 47
   receiving [6] = 255
   receiving [7] = 47
   receiving [8] = 255
   receiving [9] = 47
   receiving [10] = 255
   receiving [11] = 47
   receiving [12] = 255
   receiving [13] = 47
   receiving [14] = 255
   receiving [15] = 47
   receiving [16] = 255
   receiving [17] = 47
   receiving [18] = 255
   receiving [19] = 47
```

Could you please help me troubleshooting the issue? Thanks in advance for helping :)

---

UPDATE 1
I attache bellow a log file from Arduino for the second run:

```
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 255
[debug] SPIbuf [0] = 95
```

---

UPDATE 2

OK. It looks I have found a solution. I had to reset IN buffer in Raspberry Pi code part. I have added the following line before calling wiringPiSPIDataRW function:

```
SPIbuf[0]=0;
```

Apart from this I have also modified a bit Arduino code in case 0: and 20: sections.

It looks it works now, but code requires more testing...

Comment: What does the Arduino log the second time? Is it the same as the first time?

Comment: No, it is different. I have updated the post with serial log.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: Will have it tomorrow...